# How to determine the distance an electromagnetic field extends from a wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrons

Basically I would like to figure out how far and electromagnetic field extends from a wire with a certain amount of current running through it. If I remember correctly, magnetic fields extend forever but the force drops off quickly. Does this still happen with EMF? If yes, then how far would an electromagnetic field extend perpendicular to the wire with a pulling force $2.7 \cdot {10}^{−27} \, \mathrm{g}$. Let's say the wire is $1.3\,\mathrm{mm}$ in diameter, 1 foot long and has a current of $1\,\mathrm{A}$.

What if we increase the diameter to $2.6\,\mathrm{mm}$ and a current of $10\,\mathrm{A}$?

I'm assuming the distance of the EMF is no linear.

If there is information need to solve this that is missing please let me know, so I can try to get that info.

Comment: It's all here, AFAIK: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elelin.html

Comment: Two or things need clarifying, then you could probably answer the question yourself. (1) "does this still happen with EMF?" This makes no sense; you need an emf to drive the current through the wire. (2) "with a pulling force 2.7 X 10e-21 micro grams" Magnetic field strength is measured in tesla (T). You can't sensibly talk about "pulling force" unless you specify what it is that's being pulled (for example another current-carrying wire orientated parallel to the first wire).

Comment: FYI, most people will read "EMF" as an abbreviation for electro-motive force, not electromagnetic field.

Comment: @The Photon I did just this! So the wire, presumably, is fed with a  high frequency alternating current and is acting as an aerial (antenna), emitting electromagnetic waves? In that case, if you are a long way from it, compared to its length, the field will fall off according to an inverse square law: double the distance, a quarter of the wave intensity, half the field strength and so on.

Comment: @Countto10, OP asked about the effects of a current in the wire (rather than a charge). Which is found on Hyperphysics [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/wirfor.html#c1).

Answer (score 1):

> If I remember correctly magnetic fields extend forever but the force drops off quickly. does this still happen with EMF?

First, *EMF* is usually used to abbreviate *electromotive force*, not *electromagnetic field*. I'll assume you meant to say "electromagnetic field" here.

The magnetic field is one component of the electromagnetic field. There is no magnetic phenomenon that doesn't involve the electromagnetic field.

> If yes then, how far would a electromagnetic field extend perpendicular to the wire ... lets say the wire is 1.3mm in diameter, ...?

Since we're talking about behavior far away from the wire, the wire diameter is not very important here, and we can ignore it for practical purposes.

Then, if the wire is very long (much longer than other distances in the problem), and carrying a current $I$, the magnitude of the magnetic field at a distance $r$ from it is 
$$B=\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}$$

If another parallel wire is nearby (at distance $\ell$) carrying a current $I'$, then the force on the second wire is 
$$F=I'\ell B$$

So as you move the second wire away, the force on it drops as $1/r$.

> lets say the wire is 1.3mm in diameter, 1 foot long and has a current of 1 Amp.

If you want to consider a short (1 foot) wire, you'll need to solve an integral equation where you calculate the magnetic field generated by each tiny piece of the wire, and for realistic situations also consider how the current is delivered to and returned from your 1 foot wire segment.

So far I've assumed you're considering a DC current in the wire. If you're thinking of an AC current, then you're essentially asking "how far can the influence of an antenna be felt?" The emission from an antenna propagates an infinite distance, provided there's no intervening matter to absorb the electromagnetic energy. However since the field is radiating into an ever-expanding sphere as you get further from the source, the intensity of the radiation falls as $1/r^2$.